# Kendo Ui Grid Not calling the Read Action in MVC

Tags: user-interface, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

My read action in the kendo UI grid is not getting called.
Can someone please help.

FYI : Please don't worry about the synctactical errors if any. I have just typed in the snippet. The concern is in the javascript where the Transport read action is done.

Here is my code snippet.

********* HTML *********

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" hre="~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>


<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*********************  Code Behind **********

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetMyData()
    {int testId=1;
        TestManager mana = new TestManager();
        List<MyTestDataModel> retVal = mana.GetMyTestData(testId);
        return Json(retVal, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
    }
```

*************************  Javascript test.js **********************

```
   function PopulateWellGrid(level) {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Home/GetMyData',
                    //url: '@Url.Action("GetMyData", "Home")'
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 6,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 600,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        //detailInit: detailInit,
        dataBound: function () {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                title: "ID",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "TestId",
                title: "Test Id",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "Name",
                title: "First Name",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "Status",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "StartDate",
                width: "110px"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following to see if it works for you. I will show what is working for me in a similar setup. I have `type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax'` and `type:'POST'` and the method I have decorated with it `[HttpPost]` on the server side. However, I have two methods on the server side first returns the view and the second method returns the data.

```
function PopulateWellGrid(level) {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax',
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Home/GetMyData',
                    //url: '@Url.Action("GetMyData", "Home")'
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 6,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 600,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        //detailInit: detailInit,
        dataBound: function () {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                title: "ID",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "TestId",
                title: "Test Id",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "Name",
                title: "First Name",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "Status",
                width: "110px"
            },
            {
                field: "StartDate",
                width: "110px"
            }
        ]
    });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(){

return View();
}
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMyData()
    {int testId=1;
        TestManager mana = new TestManager();
        List<MyTestDataModel> retVal = mana.GetMyTestData(testId);
        return Json(retVal);`
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mitul.But it is not working either. I tried with GET and POST. I tried to call the read action to see if it works and here is what I tried.$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/GetAllWellsForLevel',
        dataType: 'json',
        //data: 'HeirarchyId=' + level,
        success: function (data) {

Comment: Do you see any calls being made via fiddler?

Comment: Nope. The calls are not being made. That is confusing me. Where as the Ajax calls are going through.